# Do you use the hjkl keys on Vim with a MacBook Pro?

Tags: vim

Does anyone use the h,j,k,l keys on Vim with a MacBook Pro. I find this quite difficult as they are far from the Enter key, which is used a lot.

I know that navigating Vim should be done in a more efficient way (/, ?, easymotion, etc.), but for near moves, the arrows are useful.

I know many people use the h,j,k,l to be closer to the home row, but these gets my hand far away from the Enter key, which I find uncomfortable.

Comment: you could ask `is there anyone DOESN'T use the h,j,k,l keys on Vim with a MacBook Pro?` your little finger cannot reach [Enter] on a Mac keyboard? what a crap keyboard design. ;)

Comment: exactly my point, about reaching Enter, yes. I will remap the arrows so that they don't work and see how that goes then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the context of Vim, your question doesn't make sense. The `hjkl` motions (apart from the fact that you should prefer more precise motions like `w`, `W`, `f{char}`) are used in *normal mode*, whereas <kbd>Enter</kbd> is mostly used in *insert mode* and to conclude *command-line mode*. (There is a `<CR>` normal-mode command, but it's rather obscure.)

**Don't navigate in insert mode!** Instead, go back to normal mode with `<Esc>`.

As a beginner, especially when you come from another editor, don't succumb to the initial urge to remap the Vim commands. They are there for a reason, though it takes some time to get used to them and discover their magic. (You can google for articles that describe Vim's command structure and its grammar-like use, e.g. [here](http://jeetworks.org/grokking-the-zen-of-the-vi-wu-wei).)

Comment: +1 Well explained! also for example `d3j 5k V20j v5h =6j ....` if you try to use arrow keys, you see the advantages of `hjkl`

Comment: i will follow your recommendation and disabe the arrow keys before i get used to hjkl motions then. thanks.

Comment: Good idea. There are even some plugins (e.g. [hardmode](https://github.com/wikitopian/hardmode)) that go further and disable hjkl.